# ArcGIS Routing service using two locations?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, routing

I was going through the routing example Simple Routing  which works on map click event. I am bale to replicate the same but instead of click I want the routing to take place using 2 different x,y.

Is there a reference or example for doing this with at least 2 hard coded points?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You said "I checked this" but what is "this"?

Comment: Hi,  I made have the following code to bring the data.   routeParams.stops.features = [];
                 if (features && features.length > 0) {
                     array.forEach(features, lang.hitch(this, function (feature) {
                         routeParams.stops.features.push(feature);
                     
                
                 }
             }));   And here I am getting an error feature refrence error.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aditya, here's an example based on the sample from https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/tasks-route/index.html but that instead of user input on the map takes hardcoded values as input to the routing service.  And displays the route on the map.

https://codepen.io/bsvensson/pen/NBLwMm